# Windows 'start' command for files 'in use by another process'

Tags: windows, cmd

I'm making an application that downloads video files from the internet.

The application needs to launch the system's default video player to play these files while they are being downloaded.

I'm not interested in implementing a video (or network) stream to make this work. The videos are being downloaded in sequential order. I need to simulate the process of a user clicking on the video file from file explorer while it is downloading (which always works provided that enough bytes are saved).

To achieve this I spawn a child process that runs

```
start filepath/filename.avi
```

but it fails saying the file is in use by another process.

This command also fails if I type it in the cmd while the file is downloading.

However, if I double click the file it will start to play normally in the system's default video player.

What command can I use to make the file open in the system's default video player while it is being downloaded (used by another process)?

Thanks.

***Note***: files may be of any type, not only .avi like in the example